# Vuetify v-expansion-panels not reacting to :active-class change

Tags: vue.js, class, vuetify.js, styling

I am not sure what is happening here, but seems like I can't change the class of the active-class prop of my v-expansion-panels dynamically.

I am trying to change it between green and red depending on a model state (changed by a click on a button), but even though the model changes the v-expansion-panels doesn't pick the new active class.

Might be doing something wrong here, but can't figure it out.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      edited: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    activeClass() {
      return this.edited ? 'active-panel-edited' : 'active-panel-normal';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
<style scoped>

.active-panel-edited {
    background-color: #ff000038 !important;
  }

.active-panel-normal {
  background-color: #00ff1438 !important;    
}  

</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
   The current active class: {{activeClass}}        
  <v-expansion-panels :active-class="activeClass">
    <v-expansion-panel
      v-for="(item,i) in 5"
      :key="i"
    >
      <v-expansion-panel-header>
        Item
      </v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sait amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        <v-btn @click="edited = !edited">Change Color</v-btn>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>

  </v-app>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply the active class v-expansion-panel instead of v-expansion-panels

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      edited: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    activeClass() {
      return this.edited ? 'active-panel-edited' : 'active-panel-normal';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<style>

.active-panel-edited {
    background-color: #ff000038 !important;
  }

.active-panel-normal {
  background-color: #00ff1438 !important;    
}  

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
   The current active class: {{activeClass}}        
  <v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel
      :active-class="activeClass"
      v-for="(item,i) in 5"
      :key="i"
    >
      <v-expansion-panel-header>
        Item
      </v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sait amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        <v-btn @click="edited = !edited">Change Color</v-btn>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>

  </v-app>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but still not working as expected, if you click on the 'change color' button inside v-expansion-panel it doesnt change the class to the edited one. Currently I am binding to style to achieve the result I need, but this seems not be working using active-class, which is weird.

Comment: I have updated the answer and it is applying the class according to the data property.
to make it work we have to include the style in the head.

Comment: Ok thank you its working now, accepting as solution answer now. its just weird that in documentation the active-class property is on v-expansion-panels and not in v-expansion-panel which lead me to the error and asking the question =/